# Calculating Percentage Correct For Each Question

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to calculate the percentage correct for each Question Number where Scores with a value of 1 is a correct answer. I need to separate it by form which means Question 1 on Form A and Question 1 on FormB should have different percentages. I am calculating these percentages with a table called onetable which looks kind of like this

| Form | Question Number | Scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 |

What the table actually looks like is many rows of Form A and QuestionNumber with a value of 1 that have scores of 1 or 0 and then many rows of Form A with QuestionNumber with a value of 2 and this goes for 150 QuestionNumbers until it becomes Form B and does the same thing.

I think I might need to use a proc freq or something else but I don't know what exactly to use so I don't have any code that I think would be useful. Does anyone have any advice? Below is the kind of table I am trying to create.

| Form | QuestionNumber | QuestionPercent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.16 |
| A | 2 | 0.76 |
| A | 3 | 0.42 |
| A | 4 | 0.94 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 0/1's PROC MEANS is a good way to summarize data.

% for a binary variable is equal to the mean of the values.

```
(Count of X = 1) / (Count of X in (0,1)) => sum(X) / N(x) => Mean(x)
```

Something like this would probably work for you as well:

```
proc means data=have mean stackods;
class form question;
var score;
ods output summary = want;
run;

proc print data=want;
format mean percent12.1;
run;
```

If you want to count the 0s for some reason instead of 1s you would then do 1-mean in a secondary step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `proc freq` is proper.

```
data have;
  input Form$ Question Score;
  cards;
A 1 0
A 1 0
B 1 1
B 2 1
B 2 0
;
run;

proc sort;
  by Form;
run;

proc freq;
  by Form;
  tables Question*Score/out=want outpct;
run;
```

There will be 3 kind of percentages, they calculate in different way. Find your what you want and use it later. You can also specify `norow`,`nocol`,`nocum` option following the slash to suppress display of what you don't want.